# Tool to create a worst-case string-length .ts translation file?

Tags: qt, internationalization, translation

If I have a bunch of `.ts` files, I would like to create a new `.ts` file where the translation starts with the English translation, then after that contains the remainder of the longest translation (or filler to that length), obviously removing extra `%1`, `%2`, etc. This would allow me to test layout on a translation that I can read, but that overflows in the worst way. If it worked well, it would mean I wouldn't have to look every language for overflow.

For example, if I have `"Hello world"` and `"Bonjour le monde"`, I'd like a translation that reads `"Hello worldmonde"` (or maybe `"Hello world█onde"` or something).

This seems like it's a short Python script, but less short to actually get right; especially if it calculated string length in pixels given my font, rather than just characters.

I can't be the only one wanting something like this, but Googling and searching SO hasn't answered this. Is there a tool for this I'm not finding? This must be a solved problem.

Comment: If you want actual font measurements, it might need QFontMetrics to be approximately correct. I'm not aware of such a tool.